# "The reception of the radical theory shows that when [invention/dogmatism] fights orthodoxy to a draw..."

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

> The reception given to Kimura's radical theory of molecular evolution
>   shows that when ______ fights orthodoxy to a draw, then novelty has
>   seized a good chunk of space from convention.

Options to choose from for the blank (for brevity, was able to rule out the others):

1. dogmatism
2. invention

The word *radical* means 'extreme'. So, can it be associated with dogmatism? Because a person who is radical does not listen to the conventions (or others who gainsay).

Or shall we simply associate *invention*, for we are talking about a 'new' theory in molecular evolution?

How should we interpret the latter part of the sentence to bring it to help?

Comment: They're looking for *invention* there, as contrasted with *orthodoxy*.

Comment: The second part of the sentence gives the explanatory parallel contrast between novelty and convention. Also, dogma fighting orthodoxy sounds like two of the same kind.

Comment: Invention and dogmatism are two entirely different things -- virtual opposites.

Comment: @Mitch - Sadly, dogma fighting orthodoxy is all too common.

Comment: So the latter part means, 'novelty' has dominated convention?
And @Mitch, I agree when you say that 'dogmatism' can not be it as it has to be against 'orthodoxy' (to fight) not like/with it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Invention' would fight 'orthodoxy' before 'dogmatism'.

Comment: But how did the orthodoxy get in front of the dogmatism to begin with?

Comment: Orthodoxy and dogmatism — in my eyes — have a lot more in common than invention does with either of them.